# How to plot a Polycollection created with .fill_between() in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have this code to plot

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Data
time = np.arange(0,20,0.05)
data = np.sin(time)

# Plot
main_plot  = plt.plot(time, data)
error_plot = plt.fill_between(time, data+0.5, data-0.5, alpha=0.2)

plt.show()
```

[image]

and I would like to plot, after in the code, the same plot but using the `main_plot` and `error_plot` variable. So I have this

```
plt.plot(*main_plot[0].get_data())
# Here I want to plot the error_plot (PolyCollection type)
# but I don't know how. Something like
# plt.plot(error_plot)
```

I have tried this [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31189665/plotting-using-polycollection-in-matplotlib)  with no result. I've also tried

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.add_collection(error_plot)
```

but resulting in this error

```
      1 fig = plt.figure()
      2 ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
----> 3 ax.add_collection(error_plot)
      RuntimeError: Can not put single artist in more than one figure
```

Comment: Matplotlib doesn't support adding the same graphical element to more than one subplot.  The easiest way is to just call `ax.fill_between(...)` again (perhaps wrapping the plotting code into a function with `ax` as one of the parameters).

Comment: Is there any technical reason to not be implemented? Or just nobody has implemented?

Comment: I suppose there are many technical reasons, especially when different figures might have different backends and dpi. Moreover, there is no need, as one can simply save the data and generate the plot again (saving the data needs much less memory). You might take a look at matplotlib's github issues and note that people are working very hard (during their free time).